# C# Minimum difference in a list

Tags: c#, linq

I want to find minimum difference in a list of xy point data. (can contain duplicate x values and y values)

```
Example:
List<Point> differenceList = new List<Point>() { (10,0), (10,20), (20,30), (12,61) };
```

Expected result

```
X difference = 2 
Y difference = 20
```

is it possible to do this elegantly may be using linq/lambda expressions?
Thanks!

Comment: min x difference is zero isn't it because the first 2 points have an x value of 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Point> differenceList =
            new List<Point>()
            {
                new Point(40, 60), 
                new Point(10, 20),
                new Point(20, 30), 
                new Point(12, 61) };

        var q = from p1 in differenceList
                from p2 in differenceList
                let distance = Math.Abs(p1.X - p2.X)
                where !object.ReferenceEquals(p1, p2)
                select new { Point1 = p1, Point2 = p2, Distance = distance };

        var minimum = q.OrderBy(r => r.Distance).First();
        Console.WriteLine(
            "X difference = " +
            minimum.Distance +
            " (which is " +
            Math.Max(minimum.Point1.X, minimum.Point2.X) +
            " - " +
            Math.Min(minimum.Point1.X, minimum.Point2.X) + ")");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

You could write the query and selecting the minimum in a single statement like this:

```
var minimum = (from p1 in differenceList
                from p2 in differenceList
                let distance = Math.Abs(p1.X - p2.X)
                where !object.ReferenceEquals(p1, p2)
                orderby distance
                select new { Point1 = p1, Point2 = p2, Distance = distance }).First();
```

The query for y is nearly the same and trivial

**EDIT**

Solution for a collection that contains duplicates and is using System.Windows.Point:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Point> differenceList =
            new List<Point>()
        {
            new Point(40, 60), 
            new Point(10, 20),
            new Point(20, 30), 
            new Point(12, 61),
            new Point(10, 20)};

        var q = from p1 in differenceList
                from p2 in differenceList
                let distance = Math.Abs(p1.X - p2.X)
                where !p1.Equals(p2)
                select new { Point1 = p1, Point2 = p2, Distance = distance };

        var minimum = q.OrderBy(r => r.Distance).First();
        Console.WriteLine(
            "X difference = " +
            minimum.Distance +
            " (which is " +
            Math.Max(minimum.Point1.X, minimum.Point2.X) +
            " - " +
            Math.Min(minimum.Point1.X, minimum.Point2.X) + ")");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: =>Erno: I have edited the question. Actually my point list has duplicates and return always zero when I use your query.

Comment: @suresh - you can solve that by overriding the Equals method of the Point class and changing the query to not use ReferenceEquals but instead use the Equals implementation. Make sure the Equals method returns 0 when the coordinates are the same.

Comment: @Suresh - I added an implementation of the previous comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Point is refering System.Drawing.Point. How do I override that?

Comment: @Suresh - You don't, it already has a fitting override so all that you need is to use this line in the new sample: `where !p1.Equals(p2)`

Comment: @Suresh - I modified the last sample to fit the comments.

Comment: =>Erno: Thanks it works after I modify it to `where !p1.X.Equals(p2.X)` !!! Accepeted as an answer. It is really great help from your side to make my work easier.

Comment: @Suresh - Next time I'll send you a bill when you change the requirements on the run ;) Glad to be of assistance

Answer (score 5):

"elegantly" is a big word... Elegance is in the eye of the beholder. This will work. I won't explain it to you because you didn't show what you did before asking.

```
class Point
{
    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public int X;
    public int Y;
}

List<Point> differenceList = new List<Point>() { new Point(40, 60), new Point(10, 20), new Point(20, 30), new Point(12, 61) };

Func<Point, int> getPointX = p => p.X;
Func<Point, int> getPointY = p => p.Y;

Func<Func<Point, int>, int> finder = getter =>
{
    var temp = differenceList.OrderBy(getter).ToList();
    var min = temp.Zip(temp.Skip(1), (p, q) => getter(q) - getter(p)).Min();
    return min;
};

var minX = finder(getPointX);
var minY = finder(getPointY);
```

I'll add that if you want the p and q values that gives you the minimum difference then elegance will go out of the window. Sadly it isn't easy in LINQ to extract the minimum "object" if that object doesn't implement `IComparable`.

If you really want the full data, fortunately `Tuple<>` implements `IComparable`, then you have:

```
Func<Func<Point, int>, Tuple<int, int, int>> finder = getter =>
{
    var temp = differenceList.OrderBy(getter).ToList();
    var min = temp.Zip(temp.Skip(1), (p, q) => Tuple.Create<int, int, int>(getter(q) - getter(p), getter(q), getter(p))).Min();
    return min;
};

var minX = finder(getPointX);
var minY = finder(getPointY);

Console.WriteLine("X difference = {0} (which is {1} - {2})", minX.Item1, minX.Item2, minX.Item3);
Console.WriteLine("Y difference = {0} (which is {1} - {2})", minY.Item1, minY.Item2, minY.Item3);
```

Comment: I'm using VS2008 i.e, C# 3.5. So I got two errors: 1) A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property.  2) Zip is not avaialble

Answer (score 0):

Here's another implementation of how you could do it:

```
private static int MinimumDifference(List<int> numbers)
{
    numbers.Sort();
    var temp = numbers[1] - numbers[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < numbers.Count - 1; i++)
        if (numbers[i + 1] - numbers[i] < temp)
            temp = numbers[i + 1] - numbers[i];
    return temp;
}
```

To call the method you do this:

```
var minX = MinimumDifference(differenceList.Select(p => p.X).ToList())
var minY = MinimumDifference(differenceList.Select(p => p.Y).ToList())
```