# Subsequent from clause vs query continuation

Tags: c#, linq

What's the difference between using a *subsequent from clause* and a *query continuation?*

By subsequent from clause, I mean using the `...from...in...from...in...select` pattern of building a query.

About query continuations and `into`, [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) says:

> It is often useful to treat the results of one query as a generator in a subsequent query.

So, the `into` keyword helps us with chaining together queries, so to speak. It seems, though, that we don't need the `into` keyword for this. Instead, we can just use a subsequent from clause. But, the article elaborates:

> ...use the into keyword to splice a new query expression after a select or group clause.

So, the `into` permits using a `select` or `group` before splicing in the new query. Is that the only reason to use a query continuation instead of the simpler subsequent from clause?

For instance, the following two queries do the same thing.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/pwKcQU

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var array = new [] { "ab", "cd" };

        var subsquentFromClause = 
            from first in array     
            from second in first
            select second;

        subsquentFromClause.Dump("Subsequent");

        var queryContinuation = 
            from first in array select first into x
            from second in x select second;

        queryContinuation.Dump("Continuation");

    }

    public static void Dump(this IEnumerable query, string title)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + title);
        foreach(var r in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to find out what actually happens is to use a tool like ILSpy to disassemble the code and look at it.

Query expressions are basically syntactic sugar. They are there for your convenience and then are converted to actual function calls. The compiler mechanically translates them into a series of calls to `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods. For example, the two `from` clauses are translated into the `SelectMany` extension method with required arguments for that expression.

In this specific query-continuation case:

- you would have an extra projection to do before the `SelectMany`, and
- your `SelectMany` would have access to the projection `x`, but
- the variable `first` will no longer be in scope.

The actual extension method chain call generated is kind of hard to do manually. The easiest way is to look at it in ILSpy.

I don't even think there are any optimizations done in the conversion as it is completely mechanical. If the conversion was smarter it could optimize the projection out in your example.

Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767473/linq-query-syntax-and-extension-methods) to see some instance of ILSpy decompilation.

For instance, here is the IL for your queries:

```
//Subsequent
System.String[]
   .SelectMany (
      first => first, 
      (first, second) => second
   ) 

//Continuation
System.String[]
   .Select (first => first)
   .SelectMany (
      x => x, 
      (x, second) => second
   )
```